# Is there a sourced edition of Tz'enah Ur'enah?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, midrash

*Tz'enah Ur'enah* looks like a worthwhile collection of midrashim -- insightful, accessible, and physically easy to read (this last is why I'm less likely to curl up with my *Sefer Ha-Aggadah* for an afternoon of reading -- the content is great, but the book is large, heavy, and uses small print).  The [Tz'enah Ur'enah edition I've seen](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0899069258), though, is unsourced, which has left me with questions [once already](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8562/472) and presumably will again.

Is there an edition of this, in English translation, that cites sources?

Comment: I was surprised to find no versions of this (in Hebrew or Yiddish) on HebrewBooks.

Comment: It seems common nowadays for English books to omit sources, but are you sure that one doesn't have sources? Some have them in the back of the book (I'm assuming you looked inside the book, but the first thought isn't always to look in the back). Also, I've never read the book in any language, but from what I've read about it, it seems to be similar to MeAm Lo'ez, which has been translated into Hebrew and English (Vagshal, Mozna'im)

Comment: The contents are organized by parsha, so I checked the end of a parsha and the end of the book.  Thanks for the tip about MeAm Lo'ez.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to see the [Ze’enah U-Re’enah](https://www.degruyter.com/view/product/467153) edition, by Morris M. Faierstein (de Gruyter, 2017). It has some [footnotes](https://www.degruyter.com/view/books/9783110461039/9783110461039-002/9783110461039-002.png) indicating its sources.