What Priesthood did Moses belong to?
Moses obviously wasn’t of the Aaronic Priesthood. Not only was he not a descendant of Aaron, but in fact he was higher than the High Priest.
Was Moses of the same order of priests as Melchizedek? Or?

Moshe Rabeinu was the Kohen Gadol for a time before passing the title on to Aharon. The rule about the Aaronic Priesthood did not exist until after. Why should there be a term for what his priesthood was called, and why is it important?

@ezra where do you get that he was the High Priest before passing it on? Scripture, at least, doesn’t seem to present a point at which Moses’ authority was reduced in favor of Aaron. Rather, Aaron wasn’t put to death because of Moses. Also, God made Aaron to be Moses’ prophet (Exodus 7:1-2). As for why - I’m just curious about priests outside of the Aaronic Priesthood since they existed, and they appear to have been greater

Well did Melchizedek not pass it onto Abraham? Neither Melchizedek (who is Shem) or Abraham have a specific term of priesthood. Also, the entire nation of Israel is called forth to be priests, a kingdom of priests, Exodus 19:6 but really only the tribe of Levi through Aaron's children are ACTUALLY priests. So prior to Aaron, it may very well be just generic

@JewishContext I know Abraham tithed to Melchizedek - but I don’t recall the priesthood being passed along to Abraham   Where is that found? And weren’t the Levites taken as priests in place of the first born sons of Israel due to the Gokden Calf incident?

@RyanPierceWilliams Seen in Psalms 110, the priesthood so-to-speak passes on to Abraham, that is because Melchizedek is the progenitor of Abraham. Your second point is correct and demonstrates the former. Both Levi and Reuben, whom was initially supposed to have both kingship and priesthood, ultimately, come from Abraham who, ultimately, comes from Melchizedek. This is that "order". This is alluded to in Genesis 15 where God confirms from him will all this goodness and righteousness come, Abraham knows someone will inherit this reward, God attests his seed will.

@RyanPierceWilliams Also see this answer https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/83765/21936
For some explanation as to why/how this transfer did occur. But based on a plain reading of the text, I see the transfer due to familial status and the recognition of greatness

I'm sorry but I don't understand what this means: "order of priests as Melchizedek? Or?" what is an order of priests?

@rosends see Psalm 110:4. Scripture doesn’t define exactly what it means unfortunately- but it is an order that precedes and is arguably greater than the Aaronic Priestly Order (Abraham tithed to Melchizedek after all). All priests serve their respective God(s), and a specific order of priests is a lineage thereof that presumably prescribes how this is to be done - such as via all the sacrifices and sacraments found in Leviticus. At least this is my working understanding- there maybe a better definition to go by. There can be multiple orders of priests serving God in different capacities

@RyanPierceWilliams that's a lot of presuming and asserting without any evidence. I don't see it as at all related to Judaism. The Hebrew word  דברתי doesn't connect to what you have defined.

@rosends then feel free to put forth a better definition. In either case, it’s a scriptural concept

@RyanPierceWilliams that's my point - it isn't a biblical concept.

It’s right there in the verse. Granted there appears to be a variety of translation- some which use the name and others that translate the meaning thereof, Some say “order of Malchizedek” others say “in the manner of Melchizedek” etc
